# How can I retrieve data from a Uri with an Android intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I have a standard http uri scheme that will open my app as such: http://example.com/message/samplemessage

I've placed my uri intent in my oncreate, my intent filters are fine.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiscreen);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String message = uri.getEncodedFragment();
        if (message != null) {
            setMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a nullpointerexception on the line 
"String message = uri.getEncodedFragment();

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct function to pull data from the uri or if I'm just approaching this the wrong way. But if I am, how would I go about retrieving the message (which I have added as an encodedFragment in the Uri builder) and passing retrieving that as a string?

Comment: Please provide code of creating intent.

Comment: @gio `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:path="message"
                    android:scheme="http"></data>
            </intent-filter>`